# error TS2539: Cannot assign to 'Particle' because it is not a variable.? Angular

Tags: html5, angular

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',



  template: `
  <h1>{{titulo}}</h1>
  <h2>Detalles del {{particle.type}} {{particle.name}}.</h2>
  <p>Masa: {{particle.mass}}</p>
  <p>Carga: {{particle.charge}}</p>
  <p>Spin: {{particle.spin}}</p>
  <p>Type: {{particle.type}}</p>
  <p>Fuerzas: {{particle.forces.join(', ')}}</p>
   <div>
    <label>Ajusta la masa: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="particle.mass"  placeholder="masa">
  </div>
 `
})

export class AppComponent {
  titulo = 'Modelo estándar';
  particles = PARTICLES;
}
//...

export class Particle {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  mass: string;
  charge: string;
  spin: string;
  type: ParticleType;
  forces: Force[];
}

type ParticleType  = 'Quark' | 'Lepton' | 'Boson';

type Force  = 'Strong' | 'Electromagnetic' | 'Weak';

  particle: Particle = {
    id: 'u',
    name: 'up',
    mass: '2.3MeV/c²',
    charge: '2/3',
    spin: '1/2',
    type: 'Quark',
    forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak']
  };
  //...

var PARTICLES: Particle[] = [
  { id: 'u', name: 'up', mass: '2.3MeV/c²', charge: '2/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'd', name: 'down', mass: '4.8MeV/c²', charge: '1/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'c', name: 'charm', mass: '1.275GeV/c²', charge: '2/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 's', name: 'strange', mass: '95MeV/c²', charge: '1/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 't', name: 'top', mass: '173.07GeV/c²', charge: '2/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'b', name: 'bottom', mass: '4.18GeV/c²', charge: '1/3', spin: '1/2', type: 'Quark', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'e', name: 'electron', mass: '0.511MeV/c²', charge: '-1', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'μ', name: 'muon', mass: '105.7MeV/c²', charge: '-1', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'τ', name: 'tau', mass: '1.777GeV/c²', charge: '-1', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Weak'] },
  { id: 'νe', name: 'electron neutrino', mass: '<2.2eV/c²', charge: '0', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Weak'] },
  { id: 'νμ', name: 'muon neutrino', mass: '<0.17MeV/c²', charge: '0', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Weak'] },
  { id: 'ντ', name: 'tau neutrino', mass: '<15.5MeV/c²', charge: '0', spin: '1/2', type: 'Lepton', forces: ['Weak'] },
  { id: 'g', name: 'gluon', mass: '0', charge: '0', spin: '1', type: 'Boson', forces: ['Strong'] },
  { id: 'γ', name: 'photon', mass: '0', charge: '0', spin: '1', type: 'Boson', forces: ['Electromagnetic'] },
  { id: 'Z', name: 'Z boson', mass: '0', charge: '0', spin: '1', type: 'Boson', forces: ['Weak'] },
  { id: 'W', name: 'W boson', mass: '0', charge: '0', spin: '±1', type: 'Boson', forces: ['Weak'] },
  { id: 'H', name: 'Higgs boson', mass: '0', charge: '0', spin: '0', type: 'Boson', forces: [] }
];
```

Esto es lo que me sale en la consola ERROR:

> ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(43,3): error TS7028: Unused label.
>   src/app/app.component.ts(43,13): error TS2539: Cannot assign to
>   'Particle' because it is not a variable.

Comment: Hola @delfordiazdavila, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. También puedes revisar la sección de [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Estas declarando la variable `particle` fuera de una clase, cuando debe de estar dentro de una clase. No es permitido tener declarada una variable fuera de una clase.

Intenta declarandola `static` dentro de la clase `Particle`:

```
//...
export class Particle {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  mass: string;
  charge: string;
  spin: string;
  type: ParticleType;
  forces: Force[];

 // DECLARA particle COMO ESTATICA EN LA CLASE Particle
 static particle: Particle = {
    id: 'u',
    name: 'up',
    mass: '2.3MeV/c²',
    charge: '2/3',
    spin: '1/2',
    type: 'Quark',
    forces: ['Electromagnetic', 'Strong', 'Weak']
  };
}

type ParticleType  = 'Quark' | 'Lepton' | 'Boson';

type Force  = 'Strong' | 'Electromagnetic' | 'Weak';
//...
```